# Implementing for loop in an if statement

Tags: python, algorithm, range

Am trying to solve project euler question :

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers
>   from 1 to 10 without any remainder. What is the smallest positive
>   number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

I've come up with the python solution below, but is there any way to loop the number in the `if` instead of having to write all of them.

```
def smallest_m():
    start=1
    while True:
        if start%2==0 and start%3==0 and start%4==0 and start%5==0 and start%5==0 and start%6==0 and start%7==0 and start%8==0 and start%9==0 and start%10==0 and start%11==0 and start%12==0 and start%13==0 and start%14==0 and start%15==0 and start%16==0 and start%17==0 and start%18==0 and start%19==0 and start%20==0:
            print(start)
            break
        else:
            start+=1

smallest_m()
```

Comment: you can use a range to enumerate all the value between 2 and 20: `for divisor in range(2,20+1):`

Comment: For a number to be divide by 10, it needs to end in a zero. Therefore you can start at 10 and move up in 10s. This will speed up your code 10x!

Comment: The `for in range() ` doesn't seem to give the correct answer.

Comment: @CodeCupboard you have not understood the question.The number should be divisible by all numbers from one to twenty

Comment: I understood that, but there is no point checking a number that does not end in a zero as it always fails. The code has increment start by one each loop.

Comment: This is not the best algorithm - you probably want to find the prime factors of each number up to 20, then find the product of the 'smallest set' of those. If you don't do this, you can think about the common divisor - it's not just 10, but 2520.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression and the all function:

```
def smallest_m():
    start = 1
    while True:
        if all(start % i == 0 for i in range(2, 20+1)):
            print(start)
            break
        else:
            start+=1

smallest_m()
```

Comment: This works!
I don't know the reason for the downvote.

Comment: per jpp's solution, you can use `start = 20` and `start += 20` instead of 1 to arrive at the solution faster.

Comment: I have re-factored that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution which utilizes a generator. The smallest number I see is 232792560.

```
def smallest_m(n):
    for k in range(20, n, 20):
        match = True
        for i in range(1, 21):
            if k % i != 0:
                match = False
                break
        else:
            if match:
                yield k

res = next(smallest_m(2432902008176640001))

# 232792560
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
n = 2520
result = True

for i in range(1, 11):
    if (n % i != 0):
        result = False

print(result)
```

Comment: Your solution does not answer my question since am looking for a  way to simplify the  `if` statement

Comment: How will you check without using if? Number of ifs have been reduced. Isn't that what you asked for?